# Accumulo IOExceptions in internalRead

Tags: accumulo, geomesa

I am trying to query an accumulo table using geomesa, everything works
fine, I get the correct result of the query but getting warnings
logged about "Error closing output stream". Here is sample log:

```
[WARN]  2017-05-04 13:00:00 TIOStreamTransport:112 - Error closing output stream.
java.io.IOException: The stream is closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.close(TIOStreamTransport.java:110)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.close(TFramedTransport.java:89)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftTransportPool$CachedTTransport.close(ThriftTransportPool.java:309)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftTransportPool.returnTransport(ThriftTransportPool.java:571)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.rpc.ThriftUtil.returnClient(ThriftUtil.java:151)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.doLookup(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:710)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.TabletServerBatchReaderIterator$QueryTask.run(TabletServerBatchReaderIterator.java:353)
    at org.apache.htrace.wrappers.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am also getting logs on accumulo web interface:

```
Got an IOException in internalRead!
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingSocket.read(TNonblockingSocket.java:142)
at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.internalRead(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:539)
at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.read(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:338)
at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$AbstractSelectThread.handleRead(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:203)
at org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$SelectAcceptThread.select(TNonblockingServer.java:203)
at org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$SelectAcceptThread.run(TNonblockingServer.java:154)
```

I searched regarding the same but found that it's saying something
related to overloading your clusters(which I don't think so happening). How to solve this?

Any help and suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an open bug for it on jira [refer this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO-2420)
For temporary workaround, we can disable this warning by adding the following logger tag in `conf/generic_logger.xml` of accumulo

```
<logger name="org.apache.accumulo.server.util.TServerUtils$THsHaServer">
  <level value="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```